# C# socket hangs when receive in loop - python as socket server

Tags: c#, python, .net, sockets

I'm familiar with C#, and know some python. Recent days I'm learning the book [Programming Python, 4th Edition](http://learning-python.com/about-pp4e.html) and have run the very basic socket samples: [echo-server.py](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596158118/blob/master/PP4E-Examples-1.4/Examples/PP4E/Internet/Sockets/echo-server.py) and [echo-client.py](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596158118/blob/master/PP4E-Examples-1.4/Examples/PP4E/Internet/Sockets/echo-client.py) 
They work well on my Windows, python 3.x.

python server:

```
from socket import *
myHost = 'localhost'                           
myPort = 50007                          
sockobj = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)       
sockobj.bind((myHost, myPort))
sockobj.listen(5)                            
while True:                                  
    connection, address = sockobj.accept()  
    print('Server connected by', address)   
    while True:
        data = connection.recv(1024)        
        if not data: break
        connection.send(b'Echo=>' + data)    
    connection.close()
```

Now I want to learn socket in C# too, so I wrote a C# .net framework 4.5 socket client, expecting to **receive and show what `echo-client.py` does**.
I got the C# demo from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket(v=vs.110).aspx) and made some refactor to reduce code size.

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string server = "localhost";
        int port = 50007;
        string request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + server +
            "\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        Byte[] sent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
        Byte[] recv = new Byte[256];
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(server);
        IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[1], port);
        Socket s =
            new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        s.Connect(ipe);
        s.Send(sent, sent.Length, 0);
        int bytes = 0;
        string page = "recived:\r\n";
        //do
        {
            bytes = s.Receive(recv, recv.Length, 0);
            page = page + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recv, 0, bytes);
        }
        //while (bytes > 0);
        Console.WriteLine(page);
        Console.WriteLine("result");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

My test steps:

1. If I set up a web site using local IIS, such as
   http://localhost:801, then above code can show the homepage html
   contents, this means my C# code is working.
2. Run echo-server.py, and change C# code's port to 50007, then run,
   **nothing output in console, and application does not exit, if I place a break point within the loop, I can see the loop has only run once**. The python server did output some log saying C# is connecting.
3. Comment do while loop(as commented in code), this time the output is exactly same as echo-client.py(expected).

So I'm wondering what's wrong when I'm using do while loop?

Comment: `s.Recieve()` blocks execution until data has arrived.

Comment: but why does it run well when server is under iis?